# I am doing something wrong at DrRacket

Tags: scheme, common-lisp, racket, r5rs

So I read that DrRacket is a good IDE for common lisp.
I downloaded it and have set the language as R5RS and written the following function definition:

```
(defun f (x)
  (+ 5 5))
```

However it's returning an error

```
defun: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
```

And I have no clue how to fix it, considering that defun is a well established keyword in common lisp.

Comment: Can you provide a reference where you read that "Dr.Racket is a good IDE for Common Lisp"?  Even if it did provide support for Common Lisp, [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) is a version of Scheme, not Common Lisp.

Answer (score 9):

DrRacket is **NOT** an IDE for `common lisp`. It's an IDE for `scheme`, which is a Lisp dialect, but different from Common Lisp.

The right syntax for your snippet in scheme would be:

```
(define (f x)
  (+ 5 5))
```

Comment: Even when I write `define` it's giving me the same error, also, in that case, what is a good free IDE for common lisp?

Comment: there are free versions of commercial IDE like [LispWorks](http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/). Otherwise, there's also [lispbox](http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/) which is a preconfigured version  of emacs and slime.